# Is it possible to reject a NuGet package install if the project uses another package?

Tags: nuget

I'm looking to create two separate NuGet packages (say, package A and package B) to connect to two different versions of a service. Is it possible to add a check where NuGet only installs package A if package B has not been installed?

Comment: There is nothing built in to NuGet to support this. You may be able to print out a warning from a PowerShell script. If they are two different versions of the service why not use two different versions of the same NuGet package?